# How do I find the coefficients to know if this color combination is realizable? What am I doing wrong in my solution?

Tags: dsp, imageprocessing

I tried to solve the following problem:

[image]

Part A was solved without any problem, however with part B there is a problem:

Second the digital signal processing, to be more specific, image processing, I know that:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}\beta_1\\ \beta_2\\ \beta_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_1(P_1) & \alpha_1(P_2) & \alpha_1(P_3)\\\alpha_2(P_1) & \alpha_2(P_2) & \alpha_2(P_3)\\ \alpha_3(P_1) & \alpha_3(P_2) & \alpha_3(P_3)\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1(C)\\ \alpha_2(C)\\ \alpha_3(C)\end{bmatrix}
$$

With the data of the problem I got the following conclusion, as \$S_i(\lambda)\$ is constant in the range \$[\lambda_0, \lambda_f]\$ so:
\$
 \int\limits_{\lambda_0}^{\lambda_f} S_i(\lambda).P_k(\lambda) \,d\lambda =  S_i\int\limits_{\lambda_0}^{\lambda_f} .P_k(\lambda) \,d\lambda= S_i\$

So
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\beta_1\\ \beta_2\\ \beta_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} S_1 & S_1 & S_1\\ S_2 & S_2 & S_2\\ S_3 & S_3 & S_3\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1(C)\\ \alpha_2(C)\\ \alpha_3(C)\end{bmatrix}
$$

I thought it would solve the problem, but mathematically the result is not doing well. I'm getting very strange solutions, the determinant of the matrix A (the matrix 3x3) is practically 0 and the solutions are something of 10^{34} order. What am I doing wrong, and how to solve correctly part B of this question?

Comment: I'm not sure about the math, but part (B) does ask if the solution is realizable. Perhaps the answer is "no."

Comment: @Justin  So, do you think that my reason is ok? Is it really true that: $$\begin{bmatrix}\beta_1\\ \beta_2\\ \beta_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} S_1 & S_1 & S_1\\ S_2 & S_2 & S_2\\ S_3 & S_3 & S_3\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1(C)\\ \alpha_2(C)\\ \alpha_3(C)\end{bmatrix}
$$??

Comment: I would post here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about this.

Comment: @P2000 thanks so much for your tip. I didn't know of the existence of this forum. I'm gonna post there.